# I have not webpack folder in chrome windows when debug my Angular 10 project

Tags: angular10

When I try to debug my code in Source tab I dónt see the webpack folder

[image: webpack]

And I don´t know how to debug the code now

Any idea please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After Reset Values to Default and restart chrome all is fine

[image: reset]

Thanks